# recreate JQuery parallax effect on javascript

Tags: javascript, parallax

so i was trying to recreate the background effect used in this website :https://ddlc.moe in the code source they used JQuery for the effect but i can t read jquery is it possible to do it with javascript and i wish to respect the html format

```
<div class="background">
  <div class="content" style="width:960px">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe add a bit more code. How are you doing your css?

Comment: i just wanted to show the layout of the page i m ok with css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of JavaScript libraries such as [rellax](https://github.com/dixonandmoe/rellax) which should be pretty easy to use

In your example, it looks like they set up scroll listeners that override default scroll events and edit the CSS background offset of the background image whenever a scroll happens

Edit: Check out this demo I made for you real quick https://codepen.io/mjkaufer/pen/LBQgaJ

You can edit the background image offset with JavaScript like

```
document.body.style.backgroundPositionY = contentY + "px";
```

Comment: ty for your answer i will check out this librarie maybe i find something useful

Comment: I just made a codepen for you and added it to my answer - check it out, it should help you

Comment: i was trying to recreat that website above  as a practice not for a project or any thing just i find it a simple but i was stuck on that part maybe i was not successful to capture the element from the html i had a very similar code as yours thank you for your help really appreciate it

Comment: Feel free to upvote / approve my answer if it answered your question

Comment: haha i sure tried to upvote but they said i m too new to upvote <3